# how to create a DAX measure / power query process / which returns a value from another row, which has the same date & time

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Please find below links to the Fact table and the overview of all tables. I would like to create a  DAX measure, or new column in the Fact table ("transactions"), where:

- The currency is NOT equal to EUR (e.g. "BTC"),
- Giving the value equal to a opposite value of "amount", as given in the row with EUR as currency (e.g. +5. Positive for negative and vice versa),

  - Where the date and time of the two rows (EUR and non-EUR) have the same values (e.g. 03/11/2021 and 12:28:06)
- The "type" = "trade",
- In all other cases, I think it would be best to give a value of 0.

**In my Fact table screenshot, I manually added the EUR_amt column in Excel to show what I would like to create**

I think it's also possible to add the column, then group by time and date, such that the rows with EUR as currency with EUR_amt being 0, would be removed. All using power query. That would be even better.

(The "Currencies" table just uses the distinct values of the "currency" column in the "transactions" table, via PowerQuery. Not relevant for this question I think)

Many thanks in advance!

-YK

**Fact table "transactions"**
[image: Fact table "transactions"]

**Overview of tables**
[image: Overview of tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated Column:

```
EUR_amt =
IF (
    OR ( transactions[type] <> "trade", transactions[currency] = "EUR" ),
    0,
    - LOOKUPVALUE (
        transactions[amount],
        transactions[Date], transactions[Date],
        transactions[Time], transactions[Time],
        transactions[currency], "EUR",
        0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this using just Power Query and the Advanced Editor

- Group by data and time
- Generate a custom column for each subtable based on your rules
- Expand the subtables, remove those with "0", and re-order the columns

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"type", type text}, {"currency", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"amount", type number}}),

//Group by Date and Time
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Time"}, {

//Add the Eur amt column to the grouped table
        {"EUR_amt", (t)=>let 

//determine relevant euro amt for each sub table
                eur= t[amount]{List.PositionOf(t[currency],"EUR")},

//add the column to each subtable basaed on conditions
                addCol = Table.AddColumn(t, "EUR_amt", 
                    each if [type]= "trade" and [currency]<>"EUR" then -eur else 0)
            in 
                addCol}}),

//Expand the new table
//Filter out the 0's
//reorder the columns
    #"Expanded EUR_amt" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "EUR_amt", {"type", "currency", "amount", "EUR_amt"}, {"type", "currency", "amount", "EUR_amt"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded EUR_amt", each ([EUR_amt] <> 0)),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"type", "currency", "Date", "Time", "amount", "EUR_amt"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, many thanks for this! To be honest, it's quite a bit more complex than I thought it would be via PQ and the Advanced Editor. The calculated column below is a bit more user friendly perhaps